# Searching for a string and print the first column of the first row with awk

Tags: ubuntu, awk, process, ps

I am fairly new to `awk`. I wanted to create a quick command to find the process number of my parent Nodejs process. I came out with this:

```
ps aux | awk '/node/' | awk 'NR == 1 {print $1}'
```

However, I think there should be a way to combine both `awk` commands into a single one. What is a more compact way of writing this?

**EDIT:**

While `pgrep` is more suitable for this task in specific, I still would like to know how to search and print the first row with `awk`.

Comment: Are you assuming that `ps` will always list a parent process before a child process? That wouldn't be a valid assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any text processing on the output of `ps`, there is a dedicated tool for exactly this purpose, called `pgrep`.

Simply do:

```
pgrep node
```

instead of the string `node`, you can use a Regex pattern.

For a detailed output with process name:

```
pgrep -l node
```

To get the command name too:

```
pgrep -a node
```

Check `man pgrep` to get more idea.

---

if you insist on using `awk` on `ps`, and merging two `awk`s as one, do:

```
ps aux | awk '/node/ {print $1; exit}'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This does exactly what I need. However, I still would like to know how to search and print the first row with awk.

Comment: @AlbertoRivera check my edits.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I will accept your answer. However, if that's OK with you, I would like to know how to print X row after searching. Say, I want to kill the children node process instead of the parent one.

Comment: @AlbertoRivera There are so many ways to do that but again you are doing it wrong, you should look at `pkill`/`killall`.